# Почему в not touch view вызываеться oiInterceptTouchEvent()?

Tags: android, touch-event

У меня на экране есть `view`, которая содержит несколько `view`, которые в свою очередь перекрывают друг друга.

Мне нужно в текущий момент времени работать только с первой, для этого я переопределяю функцию `onInterceptTouchEvent()`, в каждой `view` внутри основной `view` `і` в основной `view` переопределяю `dispatchTouchEvent`, где в соотвествии с приходящим ивентом управляю поведением текущей `view`.

Также, чтобы мне не мешали `view`, которые не используются в текущий момент времени я делаю их `unTouch`, с помощью `view.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> true);`

Но возникает проблема. Иногда другая `view`, которая в текущий момент еще `unTouchable`, перехватывает ивенты в `oiInterceptTouchEvent()`, но в `OnTouch` Не заходит.

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема. Может кто сталкивался?

Также при дебаге я увидела, что при ивенте `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` в `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` в основной `view` заходит в `dispatchHoverEvent(MotionEvent event)` и уже после этого вторая `view` перехватывает ивент, но так не должно быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашла ответ на данный вопрос, возможно кто-то еще столкнется с подобной проблемой. Так вот, есть очень [полезная статья](http://codetheory.in/understanding-android-input-touch-events/) на эту тему.

И вот в таком порядке вызываются функции, отвечающие за обработку и направление событий (если ни одна из View не перехватила данное событие и возвратила false):

```
Activity.dispatchTouchEvent -> EVENT->   
Activity.onInterceptTouchEvent -> EVENT->   
     ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent -> EVENT->   
     ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent -> EVENT->  
         View.onTouch -> EVENT->  
     ViewGroup.onTouch  -> EVENT->   
Activity.onTouch
```

Исходя из этого, `onTouch()` вызывается после `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.